# Nginx + Php-fpm + Zend Framework 1.11 strange rewrite error

Tags: zend-framework, url-rewriting, nginx, php

I have strange rewrite problem with nginx & php5-fpm on an *nix platform. I'm using a Router.php class as app resource and there are lot of routes in this file which generates user-friendly uri's for corresponding modules & controllers. Now, i want to move some of this regex based application routes to nginx level and when i move a route to nginx config, i'm getting "invalid controller specified" error.

Simply, when a user requests a /foo URI, i want to trigger BarController's bazAction(). It's successfully working on application level (via Router resource)

```
public function init() {
  $router = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getRouter();
  $f = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Static('foo',
                                                array( 'controller' => 'Bar',
                                                       'action' => 'baz'));
  $router->addRoute( 'foo', $f);
 ...
```

When i try to do this using nginx rewrite rules like this

```
rewrite ^/foo /index.php/bar/baz?$args last;
```

I'm getting Invalid controller specified (foo) error. How can i handle this rewrite rules correctly?

My server.config is:

```
    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  www.dummy.com;
        root         /Users/foozy/Sites/dummy.com/public;
        index        index.php;

        location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ @rewrites;
        }

        location @rewrites {
            rewrite ^/foo /index.php/bar/baz?$args last;
            # i also tried :
            # rewrite ^/foo /bar/baz?$args last;
            rewrite ^ /index.php?$args;
        }

        location ~ ^.+\.php {
          include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
          fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        }
    }
```

My fastcgi_params file is:

```
fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME    $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param  QUERY_STRING       $query_string;
... nginx's default params here ...
fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_NAME        $fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_URI        $request_uri;
fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_URI       $document_uri;
...
fastcgi_param           APPLICATION_ENV   development;
fastcgi_index           index.php;
fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(.*)$;
fastcgi_param           PATH_INFO         $fastcgi_path_info;
```

And in php.ini fix_pathinfo is set to 0:

```
cgi.fix_pathinfo=0
```

PHP v5.3.8, Nginx v1.0.10

Comment: check if this is working `rewrite ^foo$ /index.php/bar/baz last;`

Comment: @emaillenin no, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I used this manual to make routers worked [NGINX + PHP-FPM + Zend_Framework Infinite 30x redirect loop](http://www.jackpeterson.info/blog/2011-10-18-nginx-php-fpm-infinite-301-redirect-loop.html)

Comment: On a lighter note, I'd like to choke the person who started the whole foo/bar thing in code.  Using more descriptive variable names in examples makes more sense.  try "userid / jakem" and "color / red" pairs that actually make sense.